# Infinite scrolling, SEO, and disabled javascript

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am about to implement a function that loads potentially large set of data (~1000 rows with ~10 columns). I am planning to implement a infinite scolling solution (ajax, jQuery, asmx) as a performance measure. However, if a user has javascript disabled or the googlebot comes a-crawling, I would like to generate the entire set of data all as once, so that no data becomes inaccessible for either of those two scenarios.

I'm not sure what approach to use here. Should I look towards the noscript-tag perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience if you're expecting a 1000 rows and expect any sort of traffic you would need to offer two scenarios.

I would use the noscript tag and then offer a paginated view for non js users. Or, you can do as I have done in the past and simply explain that your application requires that javascript be left on (also through the noscript tag). Anyone that runs around the internet with javascript turned off is most likely going to be used to the internet not working the way it should, or only getting a partial experience.

Comment: Well, pagination for non JS-users is a pretty good solution. As for the googlebot scanario, not so sure...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a client-side pagination class with JS, 
its lightweight, very user friendly and if browser doesnt submit JS, 
No problem, he will see a huge data table :)

http://en.newinstance.it/2006/09/27/client-side-html-table-pagination-with-javascript/